# How can I make an <img> position: relative nested in a position: absolute <div> clikable with?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am translating a flash carousel to JavaScript and I am having problems with the position. This is the CSS of the div that contains the images.

```
#tiovivo{
height:382px;
    width:793px;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    z-index:-1000;
overflow:hidden; 
position:relative; }
```

If the position is not relative the JavaScript code has to be longer and the images go out of the border

The images are in the div like this:

```
<div id="tiovivo">
<img id="tio4" style="cursor:pointer; position:absolute;" onClick="location.href='tio4.php'" height="150px" src="tio4.jpg">
<img id="tio5" style="cursor:pointer; position:absolute;" onClick="location.href='tio5.php'" height="150px" src="tio5.jpg">
</div>
```

The problem is that when `#tiovivo` is `position:relative`I am unable to click the images, the events "onclick" don't work and the cursorpointer is not shown.

If #tiovivo is in `position:static` the "onclick" and the `cursor:pointer` do work correctly.

I need images "position: absolute" so I can put them easily in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Remove `z-index:-1000` to make the all elements in the div clickable.
2.) If `absolute` position for the images, you have to add a vertical and a horizontal position (`left` or `right`, `top` or `bottom`) to them.

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKjLQ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `z-index: -1000` setting.

Compare this (with the `z-index` on `#tiovivo`):

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5HZdp/

and this (without the `z-index` on `#tiovivo`):

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HLp3Z/

Your negative `z-index` is pushing `#tiovivo` and its children under `<body>` so the images never receive click events. You don't need the `z-index` to get your absolutely positioned images on top, they'll be on top by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your case

- there is no javascript involved, at least it is has nothing to do with positioning here
- you are using position absolute with no other position attributes eg.left,right etc.
- **remove** *z-index* CSS and it will work. You are placing whole DIV **UNDER** everything else even if it is transparent

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, it was the `z-index: -1000` I used this index because I was programing a "3D" effect and I want to avoid that the bottom of `#tiovivo` cover the images.

This is the function I use to update the carrousel

```
pos0+=(offx-tempX)/5000;if(pos0> 6.28318531){pos0-=6.28318531}
image0.style.left=offx+310*Math.cos(pos0)+"px";
ytilt=Math.sin(pos0);
image0.style.top=offy+310*ytilt*((offy+tempY)/1000)+"px";
image0.style.zIndex=Math.round(ytilt*10);

pos1+=(offx-tempX)/5000;if(pos1> 6.28318531){pos1-=6.28318531}
image1.style.left=offx+310*Math.cos(pos1)+"px";
ytilt=Math.sin(pos1);
image1.style.top=offy+310*ytilt((offy+tempY)/1000)+"px";
image1.style.zIndex=Math.round(ytilt*10);
```

I fixed the problem adding an offset to zIndex of the images because sin() function goes from -1 to 1.

```
image0.style.zIndex=100+Math.round(ytilt*10);
```

And removing the `z-index: -1000` from `#tiovivo`